# "He was alive, and a great hero."

Tags: sentence-construction

Well, it seems a bit weird, but I want to know whether following sentences is allowable to use in a informal context.

> He was alive, and a great hero.

> Tom is alive and an amazing player.

Comment: Only one question per post, please. I have removed your second question from the post pursuant to our policy. You can ask that part in a new question. Please take a [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and see how our site works.

Comment: can you please provide more context?

Comment: The only context in which I can imagine this being said is if a man is found to have survived some disaster in which his actions have revealed him to be heroic.

Answer (score -1):

> He was alive, and a great hero.

Standalone, this sentence could use some more clarity. When was he alive? In addition, the two details you're trying to give about the subject don't fit well together, so it's better to separate them, or make them fit well by adding some stuff.

> He was alive when that war had happened, and he became a great hero
> because of his unmatched contribution/efforts.

Coming to the second sentence...

> Tom is alive and an amazing player.

**Tom is an amazing player.** This sentence by itself tells us that Tom is still alive.